# Print End-Of-Line character in Flask, Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm using `render_template_string()` method of Flask to generate HTML code, but I can't generate the end of line character. I tried the `"\n"` character, but it doesn't work. That is, in the generated page (when you right-click -> look at the page code), all the generated HTML code is in one line.

PHP had a constant `PHP_EOL` that did the job just fine, is there something similar in Python?

The code below generates a code merged into one line.

```
    return render_template_string( '<p>' + text + '</p>' + '\n') + \
           render_template_string( '</details>' + '\n')
```

Comment: It should work for you. See [here](https://onecompiler.com/python/42392b8mq)

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe it is important that I use Flask and the render_template_string() method and feed the '\n' character into this method? I'll add to the question header.

Answer (score 0):

This is Jinja escaping issue, which is used by Flask.

Solution is use `"{{'\n'}}"` instead of `'\n'`.